# How to add additional SUBMIT handler when a FILE is uploaded on Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am currently working with Drupal 6, and I have been working on a custom module that is doing specific functionality for a site. Currently, I still have 1 functionality to be fixed. It is when a file is uploaded to node, I wanted to do other stuff. My question is, how can I capture that event? It's like

```
when a file is uploaded {
   read the file
   print an additional info to the field (a cck field)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filefield's hook_file_update().
See here:  http://www.wesjones.net/home/2011/03/drupal-6-how-to-change-filename-on-upload